# How to stream computer audio AND microphone to an Icecast/Shoutcast server?

Tags: windows-10, streaming, icecast

I need to stream contents of a Microsoft Teams video-call to an Icecast server. For this to work correctly I need to stream both the computer audio AND my own local microphone, so that people listening to the stream (through the Icecast server) can hear all conversation as it is ongoing. How to achieve this?

I installed an Icecast server and was able to stream stuff using [butt](http://danielnoethen.de/butt/) and [Rocket Broadcaster](https://www.rocketbroadcaster.com/), but these streaming clients allow me to either stream from mp3 files or from various audio devices. I need something like a mixer or an audio capture software that can also stream.

Using Windows 10 as the platform from which I want to stream.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in a bit, but first make sure you have the Stereo Mix available. Depending on your use case that might already cover things.

https://appuals.com/how-to-restore-missing-stereo-mix-on-windows-10/

Then you'll want to do some audio routing/mixing with virtual devices.

- https://jackaudio.org/downloads/
- https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm
- https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/

Or you use a multi-input capable source client. As far as I understand OBS could do that.
Also ePirat did describe streaming to Icecast in a blog post:

https://epir.at/2018/03/08/obs-icecast-streaming/

Comment: I tired it with Jack (the first tool), but can't get it to work with butt (as the streamer) and Zoom.